# Move the UIView up when the TextField is pressed

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfielddelegate

I have 2 text fields, If I click the text fields (In portrait mode) the keyboard is not hiding the textField. But when I change to the Landscape , Then the Keyboard overlays the textFields. I don't know how to set the frame size in the delegate methods (textFieldShouldBeginEditing,textFieldShouldEndEditing )so that it will work in both portrait and landscape. OR should i use the Scroll View ?? [image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to give you a 100% certain answer, both because it's a bit subjective and also because I am not able to actually see your app (print screens would be nice). But, in my opinion a `UIScrollView` would be a good answer. Another option is to animate your `UITextField`, so it can go "up" when the keyboard comes.

Comment: For your reference I have added the ScreenShots.

Comment: I don't think you actually need a UIScrollView for that. On the rotation I would put the button and the textfield where I want them instead. Think would be better and simpler.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use a `scrollView` and make other UI elements as a subview of `ScrollView`. And frame size for `scrollView` should use a whole window size even in `Landscape Mode` too (For that you need to learn `autoresizingmask` ).. And then when you invoke the `textField` and `keyboard appears` ,you need to reduce the size our `scrollView` frame to scroll even your keyboard is on view..

below is my code for textFieldDidBeginEditing and textFieldDidEndEditing method:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.2];
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,150); 
    [scrollView scrollRectToVisible:textField.frame animated:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}


- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{

    [self autoCalculateDownPayment];
    [UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState: YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 0.2];
    scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,416);
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Comment: Whats the point of the scrollview? You can do the same thing by just moving the view up by the size of the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You should set your View Controller's frame up to show the editbox (for example) on center of the screen in `(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` method. Calculations should depend on orientation. And set the frame to it's original in `(void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField`.

Also there are different approaches like using scrollview and changing it's content offset when editbox is touched.